# How long to leave traps in crawlspace?

Tags: crawlspace, mice

My pest control guy sealed up possible entrances and left peanut butter traps. A week later the traps were still untouched and the smell is a lot better. No signs of gnawing on the sealed areas. Should the traps be removed eventually? My concern is as long as the traps are there they will keep trying to chip away at a tunnel or something until they can get to that peanut butter.

Comment: talk to the pest control tech

Comment: Sounds plausible, but you need to talk to pest control guy.